# accessing a dictionary with an array of key values

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach

I have a dictionary with an array in it defined as:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> wordDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
```

is there a way in c# to access specific values in the dictionary without the foreach iteration.

Comment: You mean, other than `wordDictionnary["someKey"]`?

Comment: i am just not sure how to access the the array of values after that. I do not want all of the values. I need a specific value.

Comment: Well something like `wordDictionnary["key"][index]` should work.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was simple. I just hav enever used dictionaries in c# before. I appreciate it.

Comment: Cicade, I have one more question. If I call wordDictionary["key"][index].Length, will this give me the length of the whole array or the length of the string held at that index?

Comment: @miltonjbradley That will be the length of the string at that index.  If you just give the dictionary a key and use .Length you will get the length of the array for that key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var t = wordDictionary ["myKey"][myArrIndex]
```

For example, this will give you the whole array:

```
var t = wordDictionary ["myKey"]
```

while this will give you the value in the array at position 5:

```
var t = wordDictionary ["myKey"][5]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the key you can access it like this:

```
string[] str=wordDictionary["yourString"];
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
string firstFoo = wordDictionary["foo"][0]
```